# Send an email on VB.net

Tags: vb.net, email

Can anyone help me. I've created a email program. I'm having an error when clicking on the send button. Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class frmEmail
Dim emailaddress As String
Dim password As String
Dim port As Integer
Dim host As String

Private Sub frmEmail_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

 If emailaddress.ToLower.Contains("@gmail") Then
        port = 587
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    ElseIf emailaddress.ToLower.Contains("@yahoo") Then
        port = 465
        host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    Try
        Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(emailaddress, password)
        smtpServer.Port = port
        smtpServer.Host = host
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress(emailaddress)
        mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text)
        mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
        mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
        smtpServer.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("The mail is send!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Catch error_t As Exception
        MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

And I've got this error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name:value
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.set_Port(Int32 value)

***Edited forgot to modify it to the original code

Comment: I've tried sending using the google one

Comment: I load the value from the database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your sub
    Private Sub frmEmail_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

doesnt run when the form loads.

Because of this `port` is set to the default value of `0`

You need to tell VB.Net to run when the form loads  like this

```
Private Sub frmEmail_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

Also further on down the code, you might find that you get an error about authentication from the email server. If you get this, just below

```
Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient
```

add this

```
smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
```

it might work.

Comment: I did what you've said, but still not working. I still got this error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name:value at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.set_Port(Int32 value)

Comment: OK. Set a breakpoint on this line ..... smtpServer.Host = host .... Run the program and when it breaks, hover over the port variable on the line above to find what the value is set to. Let me know.

Comment: Cool.  What was the problem?

Comment: There is something that I need to turn off in the google settings. It is enable less secure apps

Comment: Ah. Ok.  Hmm.  If that was the problem and not my answer,  you should add your own answer. Our was it a combination of the two?

Comment: Not sure tho but I have added your code as you've said that I might get an error authenticating from the email server

Comment: I would suggest commenting it out to see if it still works. The thing is, it's important that the answer is correct so that other users searching this site get the correct information